# Ignore specific Urls from Intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-intent-chooser

How to ignore specific set of URLs from Intent Filter.
Existing filter.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

With the above filter, all URLs opens in the app. I want to ignore few URLs & it has to opened using browser.
Example urls to be ignored.

```
https://www.example.com/privacy-policy
https://www.example.com/tos
https://www.example.com/faq
```

The below code directly opens the app.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy-policy");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent); // Opens the app directly.
// startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select browser")); // Shows current app only.
```

Comment: `<intent-filter>` is a whitelist, not a blacklist. There is no "except-for" mechanism in `<intent-filter>`. You would need to come up with the right set of `<intent-filter>` and `<data>` elements to enumerate all the URLs that you do support. This will be rather lengthy.

Comment: What **android:pathPattern** have you tried?