# Open File From URL in Xamarin.Android by ignoring Deep Linking

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am working on a Xamarin.Android application.

I've defined a "Deep Linking", like :"*.example.com". Everything works fine, but I need a [blacklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663757/ignore-specific-urls-from-intent-filter) on a specific folder like "*.example.com/media/*"
(because in this folder I have only the files/attachments).

```
<!-- Activities  -->
    <activity android:name="ApplicationLaunchActivity">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.example.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> And in LaunchActivity I have

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        AutoVerify = true,
        Categories = new[] 
        {
            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
        },
        DataScheme = "https",
        DataPathPrefix = "",
        DataHost = "*.example.com"
        )]
```

So, as I've read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663757/ignore-specific-urls-from-intent-filter) , there is no blacklisting in Deep Linking in IntentFilter. 
So what I can to do is loading files in a WebView. For image files, I've no problem but for files with pptx or pdf, there is shows nothing in WebView.

```
WebView postAttachmentsWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.PostAttachmentsWebView);
postAttachmentsWebView.LoadUrl(url);
```

Do you have any idea for me? Is there any solution for forcing Android to open this specific URL with WebBrowser on not using DeepLinking? Or other solution? Any suggestions?

Comment: So, your problem is load pptx or pdf in Android webview?

Comment: The both, and generally I'd like to have the same behavior of web browser in web view